# Adding selection listener to GXT Grid?

Tags: java, gwt, grid, gxt

I'm trying to add a selection listener to my GXT (Ext GWT) Grid, but I can't seem to get it to fire. I've tried many variations of this with no luck:

```
myGrid.addListener(Events.Select, new SelectionListener<ComponentEvent>() {

     @Override
     public void componentSelected(ComponentEvent ce) {
         System.out.println("selected");
     }
});
```

Answer (score 11):

```
        myGrid.getSelectionModel().addSelectionChangedListener(new SelectionChangedListener<ModelData>() {

        @Override
        public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent<ModelData> se) {
            ...

        }
    });
```

Try this code

Comment: Very useful answer. _Note:_ this handler is fired even if unselection happens (`Grid.getSelectionModel().addSelectionChangedHandler`)

Answer (score 2):

To upgrade this answer to GXT v3

```
grid.getSelectionModel().addSelectionChangedHandler(
  new SelectionChangedHandler<ModelData>(){

@Override
public void onSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent<ModelData> event) {
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
myGrid.addListener(Events.Select, new Listener<GridEvent<ModelData>>() {
    @Override public void handleEvent(GridEvent<ModelData> be) {
        System.out.println("selected");
    }
});
```

Replacing ModelData with your model type if necessary.

Comment: It may be that your grid is not capturing the select event. When you replace Events.Select with Events.DoubleClick and doubleclick on a row does it work?

Answer (score 1):

Seemed to have found a workaround for this:

```
myGrid.addListener(Events.OnClick, new Listener<ComponentEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(ComponentEvent ce) {
        // Handle the grid event
    }
});
```

Seems like you just have to be generic about it, then you can check and cast your ComponentEvent to a GridEvent.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use GXT 2.x version ? Did you check whether required events are sinked? for example like
grid.sinkEvents(Event.ONCLICK | Event.ONDBLCLICK | Event.MOUSEEVENTS);